# how to use Retrofit for post request from Server?

Tags: android, retrofit

This is my url `http://192.168.1.217:8088/api/frontend/web/index.php?r=api/sms/send`,and I need take some params,the following is param

```
    {"body":{"param":"VjvBNGoYQ3/nCytxN0zx5rr+6sewp7FABok5N3DdDdD0WWu7KCCohA=="},
"header":{"deviceId":"","appToken":"","serviceCode":"sms","appType":1,"appVersion":1,"clientType":1}}
```

I shoud how write the code use retrofit?Thanks advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best example I have found on how to use retrofit so far http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/
But if you want to another example here is the code i used for OpenWeatherMap.

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 30;
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
         if (retrofit==null) {
             OkHttpClient.Builder okBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

             okBuilder.connectTimeout(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
             okBuilder.readTimeout(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
             okBuilder.writeTimeout(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

             Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

             return new Retrofit.Builder()
                 .baseUrl(BASE_URL)                  .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(okBuilder.build())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

public interface ApiInterface {
     @GET("data/2.5/forecast?id=524901")
     Call<WeatherResponse> getWeatherData(@Query("APPID") String apiKey);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me see, I don't kown how to define the BaseUrl?